# How can I drill down into this JSON data with JavaScript to get the data I need?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to list out all the titles of the movies in this JSON file but I'm not sure how to. I know I can list the first movie by using movies[0].title but how do you list out the second and the third and so forth?

```
{
"total": 12,
"movies": [{
    "id": "771359339",
    "title": "That Awkward Moment"
    },
    {
    "id": "771359539",
    "title": "Terminator 2"
    },
    {
    "id": "751359339",
    "title": "Sunshine"
    },
    .........
```

The jQuery I have so far:

```
function processJSON(data) {
    $.each(data.movies, function(i, movie) {
        $('#movies').append(movie.title + "<br>");
    });
}
```

Comment: the `i` param in your function is the index, that's how you reference an array or object. So `data.movies[i].id`.

Comment: What you've included here, at least, [is capable of listing titles](http://jsfiddle.net/kYQ7h/). If it isn't, can you describe the results you are getting? Any errors being logged? Is the JSON data being parsed to a JavaScript Object -- `typeof data === 'object'`?

Comment: Jonathan, you're right, it works in that jsfiddle. Here is the actual JSON data I'm trying to read. It will only list out the first title with this data and I can't figure out why: http://jsfiddle.net/9v4sY/

Comment: And that appears to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/a56tg/.